# Adding new activity always creates a new package

Tags: android, eclipse

I am adding a new activity by :

```
1. Right click package.  
2. New  
3. Others  
4. Android Activity
```

This creates a new activity but in a new package. I know we can add activity from [**mainfest file in the same package**](http://www.mysamplecode.com/2011/06/add-activity-to-android-project-using.html) but is there a possibility to add activity in already created package by the above way I am trying i.e. from Package explorer.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on package > new class. That will create the class within the package.

Comment: True but then I have to separately add layout and register activity in mainfest.

Answer (score 0):

- Right click on the package name(in which you want your activity to be added)
- Go to New
- Click on 'Other..'
- Select 'Android Activity'

  By doing this,No separate registration of the xml file will be required and the activity will be added into your desired package